# N balls distributed in N boxes

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This question is related to the following question:

[n distinguishable balls into n boxes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120819/n-distinguishable-balls-into-n-boxes)

Suppose that $n$ balls are distributed in $n$ boxes. I have two items

a) Given that box 1 is empty what is the probability that only one box is empty.

b) Given that only one box is empty what is the probability that this box is box 1.

If $A$ is the event "box 1 is empty" and  $B=$"only one box is empty" then we are looking for 
$$ 
P(B|A)= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}~~~\text{and}~~P(A|B)= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$

I have no idea how to describe the event $B=$"only one box is empty" in order to calculate the probability.

Can someone help me with this?

**Parcial Solution:** For item b) note that  $A\subset B $ so $A\cap B=A$ and it is possible to show that 
$$
\#A= [(n-1)n!]/2n^n~~\text{and that}~~\#B= n(n-1)\binom{n}{2}(n-2)! 
$$
therefore:
$$
P(A|B)=\dfrac{[(n-1)n!]/2n^n}{n(n-1)\binom{n}{2}(n-2)!}
$$

Is this ok!?

Comment: Event $B$ is exactly one box is empty. The way you find this is by placing one ball in each box beforehand (other than one box, of course), and then letting balls go in whatever boxes they want.

Comment: Notice that if exactly one box is empty, then there is an empty box, one box with two of the $n$ balls, and each of the other boxes must receive one ball.  Count how many ways this can occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a, you are told that all the balls go into bins $2$ through $n$.  You are asking the chance that all bins $2$ through $n$ have at least one ball.  If we consider the balls labeled, there are $(n-1)^{n}$ ways to distribute the balls.  To have all the bins with at least one ball, there are ${n-1 }$ ways to select the bin with two balls, $n \choose 2$ ways to choose the balls in that bin, and $(n-2)!$ ways to arrange the other balls, so the chance is $$\frac{(n-1){n \choose 2}(n-2)!}{(n-1)^{n}}=\frac {n!(n-1)}{2(n-1)^{n}}=\frac {n!}{2(n-1)^{(n-1)}}$$

For b, the bins are equivalent, so it is $\frac 1n$

Comment: Can you explain better this claim:"You are asking the chance that all bins 2 through  have at least one ball. If we consider the balls labeled, there are (−1) ways to distribute the balls. "?

Comment: If we are given that bin $1$ is empty, each ball has $n-1$ bins it can go in.  You make $n$ such choices, so there are $(n-1)^n$ ways to put the balls in bins $2$ through $n$

Comment: My question is realy basic, I apologise in advance. I was thinking that if we have $n$ balls and $n-1$ bins to distrubute this balls then by the multiplicative principle we have $n^{n-1}$ ways to do that. however instead, you are distribution bins to the balls. I cant understanding why...

Comment: The first ball has $n-1$ bins it can go in.  So does the second, so there are $(n-1)^2$ ways to place the first two balls.  We keep going for $n$ balls and get $(n-1)^n$

Answer (score 0):

( PART A )
Each desirable outcome is a surjection from an n set to a n-1 set. The total number of outcomes is the number of functions from an n set to an n-1 set.

There are n-1 surjections ; since we know the remaining n-1 boxes are non-empty go ahead and put a ball in each one. Then we'd only have one ball left and n-1 boxes to choose from for that remaining ball.

(n-1)^n is the total number of functions from an n set to a n-1 set.

Therefore, the desired probability is (n-1)/[(n-1)^n] which equals (n-1)^(1-n).

(PART B)
No matter what box the probability it is the only empty box is the same. These events are obviously mutually exclusive and their probabilities sum to 1. Therefore, the desired probability is 1/n.

Comment: Your count of  functions assumes the balls are distinguishable.  Your count of the ways to distribute the balls assumes they are not.

Comment: @Ross. I took another look but I'm not quit sure what you mean. That is, the order of the balls in each box doesn't matter. For example, if Box A has balls 1,2,3 then you shouldn't overcount and count again Box A with 3,2,1 separately so that you count the same thing 6 times.

Comment: I'm not overcounting.  If you number the balls $1$ to $n$ you can place them in the bins in order, so $1,2,3$ into bin $1$ is only counted once.  I agree with your $(n-1)^n$ as the number of ways to distribute the balls into bins other than $1$.  The numerator should be much higher as shown in my answer.

Comment: Does the order in each bin matter to you in your count ?

Comment: No, I am just computing based on which balls end up in which bin.

Comment: @Ross. Thank you. I see where I undercounted. As you noted I should multiply by nC2 and (n -2) ! because the balls are distinguishable. Thank you.